# How to send data continuously from views.py to html template in Django?

Tags: python, django, web, development-environment, web-development-server

Is there any way to send continuous data from views.py to a html template?
If I use return then we can send data only once but i want to send continuously for some time.

Comment: You can use ajax to update values based on user input.

Comment: You can use Django Channels or Python-socketio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my example of using socketio with django.

First of all, you have to install python-socket.io.

```
pip install python-socketio
```

views.py (you can put this code wherever you want but not in a template.)

```
import os
import socketio

async_mode = None
basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode=async_mode)


# this function is called whenever a client is connected to the server.
@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    sio.emit("response", {"message": "Welcome!"}, room=sid)
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import socketio
from post.socketioserver import sio

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'test_app.settings')

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, django_app)
```

client.html

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.2.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
        const socket = io.connect();
        socket.on("connect", ()=>{
            console.log("I'm connected!")
        });
        socket.on("response", (dict)=>{
            console.log(dict["message"]);
        });
</script>
```